# Single table inheritance insertion order

Tags: persistence, openjpa

I have a following situation when I use `OpenJPA`:

Those 3 entities: `SelectQueryElement`, `SingleSelectQueryElement`, `CompositeQueryElement` are implemented thought `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance.

I also have `ColumnClass` entity which holds top-level `CompositeQueryElement`. Each of these classes have `EAGER` loading and `PERSIST`/`MERGE` cascade type.

[image: Class diagram]

Now, if I want to mimic structure like this:

```
ColumnClass
|   CompositeSelectQueryElement // top-level query element
|   |   SingleSelectQueryElement 
|   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement 
|   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement 
|   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
|   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement
|   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
```

... and I try to merge `ColumnClass` object, I expect for insertion order to be "preorder". But what I get not even close to that.

**I expected the following insertion order:**

```
   ColumnClass
1   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement // TOP-LEVEL
2   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
3   |   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement
4   |   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
5   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
6   |   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement
7   |   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
```

OR at least:

```
   ColumnClass
1   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement // TOP-LEVEL
2   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
3   |   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement
6   |   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
4   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
5   |   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement
7   |   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
```

**But** what I got was this: (note that first come all `Composite`s and after them all `Single`s)

```
   ColumnClass
1   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement // TOP-LEVEL
4   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
2   |   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement
5   |   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
6   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
3   |   |   CompositeSelectQueryElement
7   |   |   |   SingleSelectQueryElement
```

Order of `Single`s is not consistent either. Sometimes it's nothing like this but all random.

**The question:** is there any way to work around this ordering issue and "suggest" to `OpenJPA` what I want to achieve.

I use OpenJPA v2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/Inconsistent-execution-order-of-INSERT-statements-using-cascading-persist-td678745.html) message from the [OpenJPA mailing list](http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/) seems to suggest your solution is to include `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.UpdateManager" value="operation-order">` in your configuration. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I am not able to this solution this until tomorrow morning but as soon as I do I will let you know if it does work :)